# Javascript RegExp anomaly

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe I'm just misunderstanding javascript regular expression, but here's my case:

I have two `RegExp` objects..

`var firstRegEx = RegExp('\/departments\?.*')` to match urls such as `'/departments?filterby=name&keyword=&paginate=false'`

and

`var secondRegEx = RegExp('\/department\/([0-9])+\/teams\?.*')` to match urls such as `'/department/1/teams?filterby=name&keyword=asd&paginate=false'`

I've tested these regular expressions in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) it works pretty much as expected, but upon running these into the browser directly, when I try to test `firstRegEx` with the second string it also returns true.

this `firstRegEx.test('/departments/1/teams?filterby=name&keyword=asd&paginate=false')` unexpectedly returns `true`

I don't know if I'm missing something, but what am I doing wrong ??

I'm running under firefox 37.0.1 and chromium Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Comment: Escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: if you create regex as strings you need double escape `\\/`.